# Conforming protocol privately

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there any way to hide protocol conforming from an end user? I'll try to describe in details what I want. I have class let's call it **EndUserClass** which conforms some protocol let's say **HiddenClassDelegate** and this protocol I'd like to hide from end user. The code looks like as it follows:

```
@interface EndUserClass : NSObject  <HiddenClassDelegate>
{
  // .....
}   

@end
```

and I want to keep the same functionality with the following declaration:

```
@interface EndUserClass : NSObject  
{
  // .....
}   

@end
```

Is there any way to conform the protocol privately? I know that I can skip delegate in class declaration but it gives compiler warning which I don't want to have

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do that by declaring custom class category in implementation file:

```
// .m file
@interface EndUserClass() <HiddenClassDelegate>

@end
```

Comment: I get a duplicate class definition, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @GooKSL, hard to guess without seeing your code. May be you forgot parenthesis after your class name? so compiler treats your code as  declaration of new class rather than category for existing class

Comment: Strange, a clean-rebuild solved it. Thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: A category without a name is also called a Class Extension or Anonymous Category. More here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html