# Privately implementing a protocol?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conforming protocol privately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813316/conforming-protocol-privately)

A class of mine tries to register itself as the delegate to a NSXMLParser object that it creates. However, I don't think I want my class to publicly disclose that it implements the NSXMLParserDelegate protocol, since that NSXMLParser object is a private variable used only from within the class.

Am I right to avoid disclosing the protocol, and if so, how do I implement the protocol without making it public that the class does so?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try putting this in your .m file:

```
@interface MyClass (Private) <NSXMLParser>
@end
```

The specific category name (`Private`) doesn't matter – in fact you can use an empty set of parentheses (see below) – but I think this should require you to implement the required methods and tell the compiler that your class implements the protocol, at least in that file.

If that doesn't work, try simply removing `<NSXMLParser>` from your .h file, and casting `self` to `id<NSXMLParser>` if necessary, when setting the parser's delegate.

Comment: After making this post, I noticed in the 'Related' that someone else had already found a solution. They suggest making an anonymous category in the .m file; `@interface MyClass()<NSXMLParser>`. If you remove the `Private`, or mention that an anonymous category works, I'll accept your post as the answer though. :)

+1 for the idea of `id<NSXMLParser>` regardless :)

Comment: I added a note. Why not post a link to that answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813316/conforming-protocol-privately?rq=1

I wonder if I should mark my post as a duplicate. I don't know how to do that.